# Can't parse midi file (time signature error)

Tags: python, midi, music21

I am trying to parse some midi files, but I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regression in v 7.1 is [fixed](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/pull/1202) in the current dev version. Until a released version is available, you can still pip install from the master branch:

`pip install git+https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21.git`

Comment: Okay so this helped me, but now I am running into a different issue: instrument.partitionByInstrument(j) this command does not seem to work as it should? Im trying to partition the stream into notes

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parts'
it says song does not have parts

Comment: I think the midi files dont have any instruments specified. is there another partition command i cld use?

Comment: To see what's in your parsed file, do `parsed_file.show("text")`, or just a slice of a few measures, `parsed_file.measures(1, 4).show("text")`. You probably don't need to be using partitionByInstrument().